# Variables binded to fields of b-table

Tags: bootstrap-vue

Lately I came across a problem with bootstrap-vue table and it's items.
I made a table with items object. I also have couple of variables, which I wanted to be a part of the table items. I want to use variables as v-model of checkbox inputs in table's template for this item slot.

I tried to put a variable as an item. The variable was seen by table, but wasn't bind to it, so any change of checkbox wasn't reflected in variables values.

The code I expected to work.
The table with template and checkbox input with v-model to component data variable:

```
<b-table class="settings-integrationsTable" outlined :items="integrationsTableItems()" :fields="print_integrations_fields">
   <template v-slot:cell(switch)="data">
      <b-form-checkbox type="checkbox" 
       v-model="data.item.model">
      </b-form-checkbox>
   </template>
</b-table>
```

```
data () {
   return {
      variable: false
   }
}
methods: {
   integrationsTableItems () {
      return {
         { model: this.variable },
      }
   }
}
```

I would love to put the variable directly in items as seen above and use it and bind it in my table input's v-model.

My workaround for this situation is that instead of direct variable, my model field of items is a string name of it eg. 'variable' and I made a method for returning it's value. I use the value to represent checked state of checkbox and second method changes it's state.

```
<template v-slot:cell(switch)="data">
   <b-form-checkbox type="checkbox" 
   :checked="getIntegrationModel(data.item.model)"
   @change="changeIntegrationModel(data.item.model)">
   </b-form-checkbox>
</template>
```

Is there any way my first idea would work? I may do something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

```js
methods: {
   integrationsTableItems () {
      return {
         { model: this.variable },
      }
   }
}
```

Should be:

```js
methods: {
   integrationsTableItems () {
      // b-table expects an array of items, not an object
      return [
         { model: this.variable },
      ]
   }
}
```

The second issue is that you are passing the *value* of `this.variable` into your items, not the reactive getter/setter bound to your component data. Updating the item's `model` field will only update it's value in the item object, and not the value in data.

If there is only one variable in data, then do the following:

```html
<b-table class="settings-integrationsTable" outlined :items="integrationsTableItems()" :fields="print_integrations_fields">
   <template v-slot:cell(switch)="data">
      <!-- "model" will point to this.model (your data) -->
      <b-form-checkbox type="checkbox" v-model="model">
      </b-form-checkbox>
   </template>
</b-table>
```

#### Update (2019-10-10):

To place a getter/setter in your items data (for the item property `model`):

```js
   integrationsTableItems () {
      return [
         {
           model: {
             get() => {
               return this.variable
             },
             set(val) => {
               this.variable = val
             }
           }
         },
      ]
   }
```

Comment: First one - yes, I know. My mistake. Should be array of course, but that's not the issue of my subject.
Second - yes, I know I am passing the value of this.variable to items and my question is exactly how to pass the whole reactive getter/setter to it. There's couple of variables in data I want to pass to items.

Comment: Sorry for late answer.
Thank you for update, but that's still not what I need. It would work of course, but the thing is, those variables are defined individually elsewhere and on this view I just use them after importing.
Your fix would be nice for 1-2 variables, but too long for 10 or more variables which is my case.